# How to parse a file to return a list of uppercase lines without numbers?

Tags: python, regex, loops

Here is my input file:

```
THIS IS A TITLE

1. THIS IS A SUBTITLE

This is body text.
This is body text.

This is body text.
This is body text.

THIS IS A TITLE

This is body text.

THIS IS A TITLE

1. THIS IS A SUBTITLE

2. THIS IS A SUBTITLE

This is body text.
This is body text.
```

I want to create a list of just titles, but not subtitles or body text. How do I do that? So far, I thought of looping through the file, grabbing the line if it `isupper()`, but that grabs the subtitles too. `isalpha()` rejects any titles with spaces in the line, so that doesn't work. What can I do? I prefer to loop rather than regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner for you once you read in the file:

INPUT (if read as one string):

```
output = [t for t in [i for i in s.split('\n') if all(j.isupper() for j in i.split())] if t!='']
```

INPUT (if read as file with separate lines):

```
output = [t for t in [i for i in lines if all(j.isupper() for j in i.split())] if t!='']
```

OUTPUT:

```
['THIS IS A TITLE', 'THIS IS A TITLE', 'THIS IS A TITLE']
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. How does this avoid the subtitle lines? I am trying to parse your one line of code, and I cannot figure out how the `all` portion skipped over them.

Comment: Good question: all() must be satisfied for all iterations of the loop in order to return True, therefore I split the line 'i' in lines into individual words and then iterate through each word 'j' to check that it is all uppercase. The subtitle lines are skipped because they include '1.' or '2.' which will cause all() to return False for that line 'i'

Answer (score 1):

Without regular expressions you can do it like this:

```
# Read the file in as a single string, with all the newlines intact.
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    file_str = f.read()

# Split into paragraphs
paragraphs = file_str.split('\n\n')

titles = []
for p in paragraphs:
    # Split a paragraph into lines, and get the first line of the paragraph
    # (which is the title).
    titles.append(p.split('\n')[0])
```

If you put the sample input you provided in the question into `file.txt`, variable `titles` will end up with:

```
['THIS IS A TITLE', 'THIS IS A TITLE', 'THIS IS A TITLE']
```

Comment: Sorry, I misrepresented how clean my input file is. I have edited my original question to better reflect how messy it really is.

Comment: @ChuckBeans In that case, it's best to use a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line into a list, and then use regex:

```
import re
data = filter(None, [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')])
new_data = [i for i in data if re.findall('^[A-Z\s]+$', i)]
```

Output:

```
['THIS IS A TITLE', 'THIS IS A TITLE', 'THIS IS A TITLE']
```